# Why Numeric work with negative values in Swift?

Tags: swift

I made this down 2 function, both working same, I was expecting that the func with Numeric protocol gave error when I am using negative Number, but the error does not happend! Now that both working, why this is happening? when I need Numeric and when I need SignedNumeric in such function?

```
func addition<T: Numeric>(a: T, b: T) -> T {
  return a + b
}
    
func addition<T: SignedNumeric>(a: T, b: T) -> T {
  return a + b
}
```

use case:

```
let add = addition(a: -3, b: -2)
```

Comment: Basically `SignedNumeric` inherits `Numeric` protocol. So, whatever type conforms to `SignedNumeric`, conforms also to `Numeric` protocol.

Comment: @willy `Numeric` is a protocol and `T` is a generic type. `addition(a: -3, b: -2)` will automatically call the `SignedNumeric` if you have both methods in your project. As others have already mentioned `Numeric` englobe signed and unsigned numeric types. So your second method `SignedNumeric` is just more restrictive than `Numeric`. **"I was expecting that the func with `Numeric` protocol gave error when I am using negative Number"** Why? `Int` conforms to `Numeric` as well as `UInt`. And Btw there is no `UnsignedNumeric` protocol which would complain if you pass a negative number.

Comment: @LeoDabus, thanks for helping, I do not want use both Numeric and SignedNumeric! I wanted know why SignedNumeric exist because I can use Numeric even for negative values, Apple says : **A type that can represent both positive and negative values.** about SignedNumeric.

Comment: If you would like to constrain a method to only unsigned numeric types (integers) what you are looking for is `UnsignedInteger` protocol.

Comment: @willy `SignedNumeric` excludes unsigned integer types. It exists to make sure all conforming types supports negative values.

Comment: @LeoDabus: Why no one does not understand me? LoL. look, signedNumeric is going to extend Numeric for: **"both positive and negative values"** my question is here, why do I should need signedNumeric, because I can feed negative value with using just Numeric

Comment: Again I never said you need `UnsignedNumeric` I said it doesn't exist (they are all integers). If you need only positive values you can use `UnsignedInteger` protocol. `SignedNumeric` exclude all types that can not represent negative values. It is simple. `Numeric` types as I said englobe signed and unsigned integers while `SignedNumeric` contains only signed integers (and FloatingPoint types which are all signed).

Answer (score 4):

Func with `Numeric` protocol shouldn't throw any error in your use case because it doesn't exclude any negative numbers.
Instead, this will throw error:

```
func addition<T: UnsignedInteger>(a: T, b: T) -> T {
  return a + b
}

let add = addition(a: -3, b: -2)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is about protocol inheritances and compiler is right.

A type that can represent both positive and negative values.
The `SignedNumeric` protocol extends the operations defined by the
`Numeric` protocol to include a value's additive inverse.

```
public protocol SignedNumeric : Numeric {
```

---

To add `Numeric` protocol conformance to your own custom type, implement
the required initializer and operators, and provide a `magnitude` property
using a type that can represent the magnitude of any value of your custom
type.

```
public protocol Numeric : AdditiveArithmetic
```

---

As you see Numeric inherite from AdditiveArithmetic protocol. So if we check out AdditiveArithmetic protocol as well we understand compiler is right

For example try this functions in your playgrounds:

```
func addition<T: SignedNumeric>(a: T, b: T) -> T {
  print("deep")
  return a + b
}

func addition<T: Numeric>(a: T, b: T) -> T {
  print("deeper")
  return a + b
}

func addition<T: AdditiveArithmetic>(a: T, b: T) -> T {
  print("moore deeper")
  return a + b
}

let add = addition(a: -3, b: -2) // prints deep
```

What about this one :

```
func addition<T: Numeric>(a: T, b: T) -> T {
  print("deeper")
  return a + b
}

func addition<T: AdditiveArithmetic>(a: T, b: T) -> T {
  print("moore deeper")
  return a + b
}

let add = addition(a: -3, b: -2) // Any guess ? Yes this is protocol inheritance so prints "deeper".
```